# Get Custom Objects Property Value from String Variable

Tags: java, android, class

I know in JavaScript you can call `myCustomObject['something']` and get the value back.

***Is there a way to do that in Java?***

I have a custom object **Student**:

```
public class Student  {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String year;
    private String homeroom;

    public String getName() {  return name; }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String getId() {  return id; }

    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getYear() { return year; }

    public void setYear(String year) { this.year = year; }

    public String getHomeroom() { return homeroom;  }

    public void setHomeroom(String homeroom) { this.homeroom = homeroom;  }

}
```

I would like a way to call a method to get a property such as `Student.getValueForKey(key)`. Where `key` could be any of the properties of the Student class: name, id, year, etc..

*I do not want to call the actual getters: `getId()`, `getYear()` etc...*

I have tried `student[id]`, but the object isn't an array. I need a way to get a property via a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You could use reflection to retrieve the field name matching to a String name parameter and get the associated value.

2) A more elegant solution if suitable could be replacing Student class by an `Enum` to store attributes of a Student and an `EnumMap` instance to represent a Person:

```
public enum StudentAttributes {
    NAME, ID, YEAR, HOME_ROOM;
}
```

And then do :

```
EnumMap<StudentAttributes, String> studentOne = new EnumMap<StudentAttributes, String>(StudentAttributes.class);

studentMap.put(StudentAttributes.NAME, "john");
studentMap.put(StudentAttributes.YEAR, "1945");
...
String name = studentMap.get(StudentAttributes.NAME);
String year = studentMap.get(StudentAttributes.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, it's fundametal to call getId() in java, another way is to call it through reflection, but it will impact on you performance, as well as it will require a lot more code to setup